# Substitute square bus in csh script

Tags: variable-substitution, csh

I have input list:   `adr[0]` `adr[1]` `xadr[0]`

I want my output is: `adr[*]` `adr[*]` `xadr[*]`

```
#! /bin/csh -fv
set list = "adr[0] adr[1] xadr[2]"
foreach f (${list})
    set f_tmp = `echo "$f" | sed "s/[0-9]/*/g"`
    echo "$f_tmp"
end
```

But it cannot work.
Someone can help me this issue?

Comment: Is the issue that you are getting a `foreach: No match.` error, or does something else happen?

Comment: Yes, I get error in foreach and substitute when using square bus [ ]

Comment: I don't have time to test this now, but I think all  you need is single-quotes on your `sed`, i.e. `sed 's/[0-9]/*/g'`